# CRC fail when extracting sample Unity project

Tags: unity-game-engine, parse-platform, zip, crc

How do I properly extract the zip files located at 
https://parse.com/downloads/windows/ParseUnityStarterProject-CSharp/latest
and
https://parse.com/downloads/windows/Parse/latest

I have tried the built in Windows zip functionality and 7zip run with administrator privileges. I tried reporting it as a bug to Parse but their bug tracking system gave me a 404 when I tried to submit.

The specific pathways to get to those URLs are 
Parse.com -> Docs -> Get Started link under Start building -> Data -> Unity -> New Project -> Download the blank Unity project

Comment: Questions about general computing hardware and software are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming. You may be able to get help on Super User http://superuser.com - Furthermore, a CRC error simply indicates a corrupt or incomplete archive. Try re-downloading it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to use WinRAR instead of 7zip or the built in Windows zip functionality. It was not simply a matter of re-downloading, the directories produced by WinRAR versus 7zip were different.